# Delete those elements from the list that are indexed in another list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
List<Double> elements = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Integer> usedElements = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i=0; i<usedElements.size(); i++)
{
    elements.remove(usedElements.get(i));       
}
```

There is a List of indexes called `usedElements`. I need to delete those elements from the List `elements` that are mentioned in `usedElements`. How to do this in a correct way.

Comment: What order is your `usedElements` list in? It matters... because after you've removed the first element, everything else will shuffle up...

Comment: That's the case. Therefore I posted this topic. E.g. usedElements = <0, 2, 1, 4>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it easier to create a new list instead of trying to modify the original list in place:

```
Set<Integer> used = new HashSet<>(usedElements);  // maybe use a set in the
                                                  // first place?

List<Integer> newElements = 
                       new ArrayList<>(elements.size() - used.size());

for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    if (!used.contains(i))
        newElements.add(elements.get(i));
}

elements = newElements;
```

This entire process is O(n).

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Sets have faster containment tests than lists (constant time vs linear time). Also, a set just makes more sense here; you have an unordered collection of unique integers.

Answer (score 3):

If you know your `usedElements` list is in ascending order, the simplest approach would be to remove the elements in *reverse* order - that way the "shuffling up" effect won't affect any of the later operations:

```
List<Double> elements = ...;
List<Integer> usedElements = ...;

for (int i = usedElements.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    elements.remove(usedElements.get(i));       
}
```

If `usedElements` *isn't* currently sorted, it would be best to just sort it first. If `usedElements` isn't currently sorted *and* you need to maintain its current order for another reason, then create a copy first, and sort that:

```
List<Double> elements = ...;
List<Integer> usedElements = ...;
List<Integer> sortedUsedElements = new ArrayList<Integer>(usedElements);
Collections.sort(sortedUsedElements);

for (int i = sortedUsedElements.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    elements.remove(sortedUsedElements.get(i));       
}
```

Or even sort the copy in reverse order and use an enhanced for loop:

```
List<Double> elements = ...;
List<Integer> usedElements = ...;
List<Integer> sortedUsedElements = new ArrayList<Integer>(usedElements);
Collections.sort(sortedUsedElements, Collections.<Integer>reverseOrder());

for (Integer index : sortedUsedElements) {
    elements.remove(index);
}
```

Comment: `int i = usedElements.size();` would be IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated, wouldn't just creating a new list without the specified elements be faster and simpler?

Comment: JonSkeet made a mistake which I did not! I will die happy! (though he was still 51 seconds quicker, while having the original idea though, I have to improve on that...)

Comment: @arshajii: That depends. The OP may have references to the existing list elsewhere, and have a requirement to modify it in place. Also, it's possible that the collection is enormous and only needs elements near the end removing from it. So it's not necessarily faster, either.